# Dendrogram with 3 types of interactions - alternative to hierarchical clustering

Tags: clustering, matlab, hierarchical-clustering

I have a matrix of interactions (1), avoidance (-1) and no interaction (0). I would like to cluster the matrix. I used hierarchical clustering but I was not very satisfied with the results. Any alternatives? Is is possible to use Louvain community detection with different interactions types?

Example matrix:

Im1 -1 1 0 1
Im2 -1 1 1 1
Im3  0 -1 1 1
Im4  0 -1 1 0

The results should highlight Im1/Im2 and Im3/Im4 as two independent branches

Comment: Shouldn't this matrix be symmetric?

Comment: I am comparing the interactions column wise, so no

Comment: Ah, I see. You need to better label. Hierarchical clustering works fine here. The top two rows have distance 1, the bottom two also, but.e.g. 2 to 3 have distance sqrt(5) which is much larger. So unless you call the function incorrectly, it should work.